# I want my Ubuntu terminal titles to automatically be set to just the last part of the path

Tags: 14.04

I read in another post that if I prepend `\[\e]0;\W\a\]` to my `PS1` variable that my terminal tabs will be set to the current directory without the path.  I tried this but it isn't working.  The post I saw is almost 4 years old so I'm wondering what has changed.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

This is what I get when I type "echo $PS1" in terminal:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\](^)#(^)#(^)#(^)\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w$
```

This is what my prompt looks like:

```
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: In a terminal, please run `echo "$PS1"` and post the output in your question.

Comment: I'm reading your PS1 and not seeing `\[\e]0;\W\a\]` anywhere in it. So what command did you run (or what file did you edit) to change the PS1?

Comment: Also, just curious, what's with the `(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)` ?

Comment: You're right I was using the wrong syntax.  This is what my PS1 variable was: `PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h:\w\a\](^)#(^)#(^)#(^)\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$ "` I made the change you mentioned to this: `PS1="\[\e]0;\W\a\](^)#(^)#(^)#(^)\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$ "` but there was not change.

Comment: The `(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)` just helps me find my last prompt when several lines of text vomit across my screen after any given command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PS1 you posted has two XTerm set-title sequences in it:

- `\[\e]0;\W\a\]`
- `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]`

The latter one will overwrite the title, so just remove it:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\W\a\](^)#(^)#(^)#(^)${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$ '
```

Also note that I used single quotes for the above. That's to make variables dynamic, not static, though it's not a big deal in this case.

---

BTW, instead of using `(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)` to find your prompt, I might suggest something a bit more slick. For example, this prints a full line of hashes:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "#%.0s" $(seq $COLUMNS); echo'
###################################################################################
$
```

Personally, I have a big bold colour prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a terminal and run:

```
echo $PS1
```

and post it here so we can see the whole thing. By just looking at what you post it seems to me that you are missing back slashes and the first and last brackets as so:

```
\[\e]0;\W\a\]
```

Hopefully that does the trick.

Comment: It's not missing the backslashes. They're in the post, but they got eaten by the markdown engine. The question has just been edited to fix this.